# PHP extension in C: _SERVER is NULL in RINIT function

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I'm trying to get some of `_SERVER` variables, e.g. `REMOTE_ADDR` or `DOCUMENT_ROOT` in `RINIT` function (extension request initialization phase):

```
...
    _SERVER = Z_ARRVAL(PG(http_globals)[TRACK_VARS_SERVER]);

    if (_SERVER == NULL) {
        _log("_SERVER is null");
        return;
    }

    if (_G(doc_root) == NULL && (NULL != (tmp = zend_hash_str_find(_SERVER, "DOCUMENT_ROOT", sizeof("DOCUMENT_ROOT") - 1)))) {
        _G(doc_root) = Z_STRVAL_P(tmp);
    } 
...
```

But the variable `_SERVER` is `NULL` in `RINIT`. When I execute the same code after `RINIT` (e.g. in compile_file), it has normal value and I can extract any `_SERVER` elements.

It seems, that it's not initialized by `RINIT` phase, but according to the extension work cycle it should be already filled in. And all extensions I've seen, extract data in `RINIT` function so it should work.

Any clue why it might happen and how to fix that?

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Seems zend_is_auto_global(...) solved the issue:

```
zend_string *server = zend_string_init("_SERVER", sizeof("_SERVER") - 1, 0);
zend_is_auto_global(server);    
_SERVER = Z_ARRVAL(PG(http_globals)[TRACK_VARS_SERVER]);
zend_string_release(server);
```